# How to increase numeric value present in a string

Tags: vb.net

I'm  using this query in  vb.net

```
Raw_data = Alltext_line.Substring(Alltext_line.IndexOf("R|1"))
```

and I want to increase `R|1` to `R|2`, `R|3` and so on using for loop.

I tried it many ways but getting error

> string to double is invalid

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Show your code. That single line doesn't explain what is your problem

Comment: As suggested, you should show us what you're doing so that we can see what you're doing wrong.  That said, my guess is that you are trying to manipulate the `String` you already have, which would be the wrong approach.  You should use a `For` loop and then build a new `String` each time using the loop counter.

Comment: Why do you have the seemingly random "filereader" tag on this question?  Please only apply relevant tags.  I have removed that one.

Comment: Editing your question to add a small sample of the data around an occurence of "R|1" might be helpful.

Comment: Try type casting, increase and then convert it back to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first extract the number from the string. If the text part (`"R"`) is always separated from the number part by a `"|"`, you can easily separated the two with `Split`:

```
Dim Alltext_line = "R|1"
Dim parts = Alltext_line.Split("|"c)
```

`parts` is a string array. If this results in two parts, the string has the expected shape and we can try to convert the second part to a number, increase it and then re-create the string using the increased number

```
Dim n As Integer
If parts.Length = 2 AndAlso Integer.TryParse(parts(1), n) Then
    Alltext_line = parts(0) & "|" & (n + 1)
End If
```

Note that the `c` in `"|"c` denotes a `Char` constant in VB.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution that takes advantage of the String type defined as an Array of Chars.

I'm using [string.Concat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Concat%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) to *patch together* the resulting `IEnumerable(Of Char)` and `CInt()` to convert the string to an Integer and sum 1 to its value.

```
Raw_data = "R|151"

Dim Result As String = Raw_data.Substring(0, 2) & (CInt(String.Concat(Raw_data.Skip(2))) + 1).ToString
```

This, of course, supposes that the source string is directly convertible to an Integer type.
If a value check is instead required, you can use [Integer.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Int32.TryParse);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) to perform the validation:

```
Dim ValuePart As String = Raw_data.Substring(2)
Dim Value As Integer = 0

If Integer.TryParse(ValuePart, Value) Then
    Raw_data = Raw_data.Substring(0, 2) & (Value + 1).ToString
End If
```

If the left part can be variable (in size or content), [the answer provided by Olivier Jacot-Descombes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53915181/7444103) is covering this scenario already.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub IncrVal()
    Dim s = "R|1"
    For x% = 1 To 10
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "[0-9]+", Function(m) Integer.Parse(m.Value) + 1)
    Next
End Sub
```